# No package.json on docker

Tags: reactjs, docker

I am creating a docker image of a react-app and it return me an error that:

> no such file or directory, open '/package.json'
>
> Notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this
>   file.

Here the Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Docker file you need to specify the COPY execution to send to the container before execute copy the package.json, modified your Docker file to be like this:

```
FROM node:alpine
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --no-package-lock
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
```

> COPY package.json .

This command is to copy your package.json to the new container

> RUN npm install --no-package-lock

This one is to install all of the dependencies of your project on the new container

> COPY . .

This on is to move all your code to the new container

Comment: let me modify my Docker file